# Angular forms: validate complete form group if a single value changes

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-validation

Is it possible to add a single validator to a formGroup, which is beeing called as soon as a single value inside the formGroup changes?

I think it should look like this:

```
'group': this.formBuilder.group({
    'value1': [''],
    'value2': [''],
    'value3': ['']
  }, [MyCustomValidator]),
```

but the validator is not invoked on changes happening inside the formGroup,... I can add the validator to each field individually and then call the `control.parent` (which is working), but this doesn't seem to be like a proper solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way of using the validator, it's fired each time value1 and value2 get their values changed:

```
 this.fb.group({
            value1: ['', [this.validateService.isNumber]],
            value2: ['', [this.validateService.isNumber, this.validateService.isLessThanHundred]],
        }, { validator: this.validateService.countInputs });
```

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/YlZVZJgVZwdIWyA2U3wB?p=preview)

Comment: thx, didn't thought about that I have to evalute each field so that the evaluation of the group is fired as well, but now that I see it, it totally makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OnChanges interface from angular.

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
    // call the validation method
    // this.formBuilder.group.valid property 
}
```

For more detail documentation, please click [here](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges) 
OR
use AfterViewChecked from [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#afterview)

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
 this.formBuilder.group.valueChanges.subscribe(()=> {
    //do whatever you want; eg: enable the save or update button
 });
}
```

Please click [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) for angular life cycle hooks.

Comment: this may be an option but it seems a bit hacky, the solution of @Vega is the offical way to go